# media player plays audio file (.wav) with echo in Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using the below code to Play Audio file  (.wav), but it plays the file with Echo(like playing two voice simultaneously) when activity is in Landscape mode.

```
public class Find_n_Display_StationActivity extends Activity 
{
 GPSTracker gps;
 TextView txtvw,locNameTV;
 boolean calculating_distance=false;
 ArrayList<String>data=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String>latArray=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String>longArray=new ArrayList<String>();
 MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

 ImageView profileIV;
 PendingIntent intent;
 String reached_station="empty";
 MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.find_n__display__statn_activity);

    txtvw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    locNameTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    profileIV=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image11);


    profileIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //Put in LANDSCAPE MODE...
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);     



    //Show FULL-SCREEN Activity
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     //Calling/Starting Thread to Handl Uncaught Exeption
     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(onRuntimeError);  

        //(((( This will retrieve DATA from service to this Activity ))))
        gps = new GPSTracker(this);
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(
             mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("GPSLocationUpdates"));

       //  mp=new MediaPlayer();

}//EOF Oncreate Method...

//(((( This Function is Called if App Crash, So, App is start Automatically after crash ))))
 private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler onRuntimeError= new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() 
 {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) 
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
 };


// ((((  This Class Get Data From Service class GPSTracker.class() ))))
 private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Get extra data included in the Intent
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("Status");
                Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("Location");
             Location   lastKnownLoc = (Location) b.getParcelable("Location");
                if (lastKnownLoc != null) 
                {
                    String s1=String.valueOf(lastKnownLoc.getLatitude());
                    String s2=String.valueOf(lastKnownLoc.getLongitude());

                double  current_lat=Double.parseDouble(s1);
                double  current_long=Double.parseDouble(s2);
                 txtvw.setText("____________________________\n\n\n"+current_lat+"\n"+current_long);
                 //showtoast("You have changed your Location");

               if(calculating_distance==false)
                {
                    calculating_distance=true;

                    FindDistance(current_lat,current_long);
                }

                 Turn_On_Screen();
                }
          }};
private String  stationPlayed="empty";


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void Turn_On_Screen()
{
    WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
             PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        screenLock.acquire();

        //later
        //screenLock.release();
}

          //(((( Find Distance Betwee All Points ))))))
public void FindDistance(double current_lat,double current_long)
{
    Move_App_Back_to_ForeGround();

     ArrayList<String>stationNameArray=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String>imageArray=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String>voiceArray=new ArrayList<String>();

     imageArray=db.Get_ImageList();
     voiceArray=db.Get_VoiceList();

     stationNameArray=db.Get_StionNameAraay();

    latArray=db.Get_LatAraay();
    longArray=db.Get_LongAraay();

    float smallest_dis=10000;
    String next_station="";
    boolean found_station=false;

    for(int i=1;i<latArray.size();i++)
    {
        float lat1 = Float.parseFloat(latArray.get(i));
        float long1 = Float.parseFloat(longArray.get(i));

       float dis=FindDistance((float)current_lat,(float)current_long,lat1, long1);
        if(dis<smallest_dis)
        {
            smallest_dis=dis;
            next_station=stationNameArray.get(i);

        }
       if(dis<=50)
       {
          Set_Pic_n_Voice(imageArray.get(i),voiceArray.get(i),stationNameArray.get(i));
            //  showtoast("station-name="+ stationNameArray.get(i));
         break;          
       }

    }
    locNameTV.setText("You are Heading towards Station="+next_station+"\n You are only "+smallest_dis+" Meter away...");

    calculating_distance=false;

}


public void Set_Pic_n_Voice(String image,final String voice,final String station_name)
{
    DisplayImage(image);

        if(!reached_station.equalsIgnoreCase(station_name))
         reached_station=""+station_name; //Don't play voice for same station just display pic always

    //Wait for 4 seconds to play this voice
    Runnable r = new Runnable() 
    {

        public void run()
        {   
            if(!stationPlayed.equalsIgnoreCase(station_name))
            {
               PlayVoice(voice);
               stationPlayed=station_name;
            }
        }
    };

    android.os.Handler h = new android.os.Handler();
    h.postDelayed(r, 5000);// */



}


//(((( Displaying Picture For the Station ))))
public void DisplayImage(String image)
{
    profileIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Bus_StationApp_Folder/Images",image);

        if (imageFile.exists()) 
        {

    File imgFile = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()); // path of your file
    Picasso.with(this).load(Uri.fromFile(new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()))).into(profileIV);
        /*  
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                //options.inSampleSize = 8;
                //options.inPurgeable = true;
               // options.inScaled = true;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null,options);
              profileIV.setImageBitmap(bm);//*/
         }
        else
            profileIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_station_pic);

}


//(((( Playing Voice For The Station )))))) 
public void PlayVoice(String voice)
{

    calculating_distance=true;

//  Play_Audio_File ob=new Play_Audio_File(this);
    //ob.PlayVoice(voice);

     File voiceFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Bus_StationApp_Folder/Voices",voice);

    if (voiceFile.exists()) 
    {


     if(!mp.isPlaying())
       {  

          mp.reset();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(voiceFile.getAbsolutePath());
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         mp.start();
       }
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                calculating_distance=false;
            }
        });
    }
    else            
    {   
        //mp.reset();
         mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.default_station_voice);
         if(!mp.isPlaying())
          { 

           mp.start();
          }
         mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
         {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
                {
                    calculating_distance=false;
                }
            });

    }

    //*/ 


}

        //((((( Find distance between two geolocation  )))
public float FindDistance(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2)
        {
             double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
                double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
                double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
                double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                           Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                           Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
                double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
                float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

                return dist;

        }


//((( Move App To Screen from Background ))))
public void Move_App_Back_to_ForeGround()
{
    boolean foregroud=false;
    try
    {
     foregroud = new ForegroundCheckTask().execute(getApplicationContext()).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {   e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(!foregroud)
    {
    //Open Activity IF it is in Background...
    Intent it = new Intent("intent.my.action");
    it.setComponent(new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), Find_n_Display_StationActivity.class.getName()));
    it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);


    }
}

class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

      @Override
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
        return isAppOnForeground(context);
      }

      private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) {
          return false;
        }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
          if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }


//SHOW-TOAST-MESSAGE
public void showtoast(String str)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void OnBackPressed()
{

}
```

}//EOF Activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are somehow calling the `PlayVoice()` method twice. The reason your inner `if` statement isn't preventing this is because you must be calling `mp = new MediaPlayer();` before calling `PlayVoice()`, otherwise the first call to that method would result in a `NullPointerException` from the `mp.isPlaying()` call in the `if` condition. Since `mp` now points to a new `MediaPlayer` instance, `isPlaying()` returns `false`, and the `if` block executes again, even though the previous instance is still playing.

To prevent multiple instances of `MediaPlayer` playing concurrently, instantiate the `MediaPlayer` only once in the declaration line, remove the `mp = new MediaPlayer();` line in `PlayVoice()` (and anywhere else you might have it), and un-comment the `mp.reset();` call there.

---

The `PlayVoice()` method is being called twice because you're requesting an orientation change to landscape in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, and you're not handling configuration changes yourself. This is causing the `Activity` started in portrait mode to be destroyed and recreated, which means that `onCreate()` runs a second time, but the `MediaPlayer` started in the first `Activity` instance is still playing when a new one is created and started in the second instance.

You can prevent this from happening by forcing the `Activity` to launch in a landscape orientation from the start. You can do this by adding `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to the `<activity>`'s tag in the manifest.  You can also remove the `setRequestedOrientation()` call now, as it is no longer needed.

Comment: yes i am using some service where it can be played twice , so how can i prevent this and can play one time only in side this function, pelase help

Comment: By the way, I don't think I made it clear: you want to remove any other occurrence `mp = new MediaPlayer();`, except for the one instantiation in the declaration line.

Comment: Are you calling the "PlayVoice" via the "onCreate" or any Activity lifecycle methods?

Comment: @RuchiraRandana The OP has stated that they have a `Service` that will be calling `PlayVoice()` multiple times. I have already provided the fix for that.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the comment. I see that being mentioned in the comments!

Comment: @PirFahimShah Yeah, be sure to remove any other `mp = new MediaPlayer();`, too, except for the declaration line. And don't forget to un-comment `mp.reset();`, or you'll get an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you probably want to find out why the `PlayVoice()` method is being called more times than you expect. My solution just stops `MediaPlayer` from playing again if it is already playing. You've not provided enough information for me to determine why that method is being called twice.

Comment: @PirFahimShah As I said, you've not provided enough information for me to determine that. If I copy and paste the method you've posted into a plain `Activity`, it works as I would expect. I have no way of knowing how or where you're calling that method, other than you've mentioned a `Service`.

Comment: @Pir I believe the `setRequestedOrientation()` call is the problem. When your Activity starts in portrait, and this line is called, the Activity is destroyed and recreated when it flips to landscape, which means the `onCreate()` method runs again, but the `MediaPlayer` you started in that first Activity instance is still playing when that happens. You can prevent the Activity from being destroyed/recreated by telling it to start in landscape in the first place. Add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to the `<activity>` tag in the manifest, and remove the `setRequestedOrientation()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. YES exactly make it answer i will vote it , THANK YOU SO MUCH